# PHP 'next image button' for a simple gallery

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using php to display a simple image gallery. One image is displayed at a time and previous/next buttons are used to navigate through the array of images. The array is also meant to continue looping through.

My previousImage() function works as intended and will loop back through the array, but my nextImage() function skips certain images in the array/continues to create problems. Any advice on what's wrong with it?

Relevant code:

```
<?php
  //total array size
  $total = sizeof($images)-1;

  //current position in the array      
  $k = 0;                      

  //displays the current image
  if(isset($_GET['pid'])){
      $k = $_GET['pid'];
      echo $images[$k]; 
    }

  //displays left and right navigation buttons which execute prev/nextImage functions
  echo '<br><a href="index.php?pid='.prevImage().'">', $button_left, "</a>";
  echo '<a href="index.php?pid='.nextImage().'">', $button_right, "</a>";

    function prevImage() {
      global $k;
      global $total;
      $k = (($k-1) < 0) ? $total : $k -1;
      echo $k;
      return $k;
    }

    function nextImage() {
      global $k;                 
      global $total;
      $k = ($k+1) % $total+1;
      return $k;     
    }
?>
```

Comment: why the `jquery` tag added?

Comment: Why don't you calculate the next image the same way you do with previous image? `$k = ($k == $total-1) ? 0 : $k+1`

Comment: I this what you mean: `$k = ($k+1) % $total;` in nextImage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need: One single function that returns the previous or next index based on direction (-1: previous, 1: next)

```
echo '<br><a href="index.php?pid='.prevNext($k, $total, -1).'">', $button_left, "</a>";
echo '    <a href="index.php?pid='.prevNext($k, $total, 1).'">', $button_right, "</a>";

function prevNext($k, $t, $d) {
    return ($r=($k+$d)%$t)>=0?$r:$r+=$t;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the result I needed! All working now

Answer (score 1):

Step 1.Make a HTML file and define markups for Image SlideShow

We make a HTML file and save it with a name slideshow.html

```
<html>    
  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slideshow_style.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="slideshow_effect.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <center>


     <div id="slide_cont">
         <img src="images/image1.jpg" id="slideshow_image">
     </div>
     <input type="image" id="prev_image" src="images/previous.png" >
     <input type="image" id="next_image" src="images/next.png" >
     <input type="hidden" id="img_no" value="0">

  </center>


</body> </html>
```

Step 2.Make a CSS file and define styling for Image SlideShow

Now we define styling for our Image SlideShow and save the file name slideshow_style.css

```
#slide_cont
     {
     box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 0px silver;
     width:600px;    
     height:400px;
     margin-top:100px; 
      }
#slideshow_image 
      {
     width:600px;
     height:400px;
      }
#prev_image,#next_image 
      {
    width:40px; 
    height:40px;
      }
```

Step 3.Make a Script file and define Effects for Image SlideShow

In this we define effects for our SlideShow using jQuery and save it
with a name slideshow_effect.js. You can dowload jQuery from this Site

```
$(document).ready(function()
     {

    $( "#prev_image" ).click(function()
     {
       prev();
    }
    );
    $( "#next_image" ).click(function()
    {
       next();
    }
    );
}
```

);

```
// Write all the names of images in slideshow 
var images = [ "image1", "image2" , "image3" , "image4" ];

function prev() 
   {    
    $( '#slideshow_image' ).fadeOut(300,function()   
        {
       var prev_val = document.getElementById( "img_no" ).value;
       var prev_val = Number(prev_val) - 1;
       if(prev_val< = -1)
       {
          prev_val = images.length - 1;
       }
       $( '#slideshow_image' ).attr( 'src' , 'images/'+images[prev_val]+'.jpg' );
       document.getElementById( "img_no" ).value = prev_val;    
     }
     );    
     $( '#slideshow_image' ).fadeIn(1000); 
     }

function next() 
    {
    $( '#slideshow_image' ).fadeOut(300,function()
        {
        var next_val = document.getElementById( "img_no" ).value;
        var next_val = Number(next_val)+1;
        if(next_val >= images.length)
        {
          next_val = 0;
        }
        $( '#slideshow_image' ).attr( 'src' , 'images/'+images[next_val]+'.jpg' );
        document.getElementById( "img_no" ).value = next_val;
    }
    );
    $( '#slideshow_image' ).fadeIn(1000); 
 }
```